# Jira - Epic validator for certain link types

Tags: groovy, jira

I wrote a groovy script for Jira Epic workflow that enables to close the Epic only if all the child issues are closed.

The script works great, and now I want to make it valid only for a specific type of linked issue. **"Issues in epic"**

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLink
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkManager
import com.opensymphony.workflow.InvalidInputException
 
// Allow logging for debug and tracking purposes
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
 
// Script code for easy log identification
String scriptCode = "Check all issues in Epics are Done -"
 
// Setup the log and leave a message to show what we're doing
Logger logger = log
logger.setLevel( Level.ERROR )
logger.debug( "$scriptCode Triggered by $issue.key" )

def passesCondition = true
if (issue.issueType.name == 'Epic')
   {
     IssueLinkManager issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.issueLinkManager
     def found = issueLinkManager.getOutwardLinks(issue.id).any
       {
       it?.destinationObject?.getStatus().getName() != 'Done' &&
           it?.destinationObject?.getIssueType().getName()  != 'Epic'
       }    
       logger.debug( "$scriptCode Found =  $found " )
       if (found) {
           logger.debug( "$scriptCode return false" )
           passesCondition = false
           invalidInputException = new InvalidInputException("Please make sure all linked issues are in 'Done' status")
       } else {
           logger.debug( "$scriptCode return true" )
       passesCondition = true
       }
   }
// Always allow all other issue types to execute this transition
   else
   {
       logger.debug( "$scriptCode Not Epic return true")
       passesCondition = true
   }
```

The code above works for all kinds of linked issues.
Does anyone know how to make it works only for a specific link type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
it?.issueLinkType
```

inside the Closure.

Then you can use

```
it?.issueLinkType.inward
```

and

```
it?.issueLinkType.outward
```

to get the inward/outward name of the link type.